# Xajax, проблема с передачей данных. ( Данные передаются как null )

Tags: кодировка, ajax, php, smarty

Перешел с **php5.2** на **php5.3**, и сразу же возникли проблемы совместимости **xajax**, обновил xajax, теперь проблема с отправкой **Smarty** шаблона через xajax.

Вот код, с помощью которого я динамически обновляю страницу:

```
$pageContent = $smarty->fetch('pages/'.$pageName.'.tpl');
$objResponse->assign("content", "innerHTML", $pageContent);
```

И у меня не передается **$pageContent**. ( В json объекте оно data показана как **null** ).
Поэксперементировав, я понял, что проблема в кодировках. Если перед передачей сделать вот так: **mb_convert_encoding($pageContent, 'UTF-8')** то все передается, но русский текст удаляется или заменяется на символы разные.

Раньше у меня стояли такие настройки:

**$xajax->setFlag("decodeUTF8Input",true);**

**$xajax->setCharEncoding('windows-1251');**

В новой версии **xajax** их убрали.

Что делать? Как исправить? Какие настройки выставить что бы все передавалось как раньше?

Comment: может перейти на utf и не мучиться ?

Comment: [Обновите библиотеку](http://www.xajax-project.org/en/download/). Они там указывают на то, что последние версии "*фокусируется в основном на PHP 5.3 совместимость и производительность.*"

Comment: Библиотека Xajax 0.6 beta 1 стоит. 

Перекодировал все в utf-8, вроде работает. Но, в этой версии xajax, массивы из jS в PHP передаеются как JSON, а раньше было как просто обычный или ассоциативный PHP массив, с которым сразу можно работать. Как вернуть эту возможность?

К тому же, при использовании json_decode($data), и проверки json_last_error(), выдает JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX.

Сам JSON объект выглядит так:  {\"account_name\":\"Testname \",\"account_email\":\"test@yandex.ru\",\"account_group\":\"7\",\"accountId\":\"1\"}